# php include for images parses image as if it was php code and gives syntax error

Tags: php, image, parsing, web, gd

I have created a script to resize images and insert dynamically in `<img>` tags something like:

```
<img src="includes/thumb.php?src=<?=$filename;?>&w=389&q=100&f=jpg" />
```

In the thumb.php, I resize image using php gd functions and finally `include` it so that it shows the resized image for the image where thumb.php is called in inside `<img>` tag.

This is how I include the image from thumb.php:

```
//header('Content-Type: image/' . $format);
//header('Content-Disposition: inline;');
include $resized_image; // which is now resized and saved
```

However it doesn't always work for all images, sometimes I receive the message:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ']' in xxxxx\thumbs\
e58b3c96d4f2ccc298d68cbac7cd97a0.jpg on line 326
```

So as can be seen the parse error comes in newly resized image when I try to `include` it. But when I open image directly by double clicking it, it shows up fine and is a valid image.

Can anyone tell me why PHP is parsing the image file just like php code, I want to avoid that and show the image instead?

All I want to do is just show the resized image like this:

```
<img src="includes/thumb.php?src=<?=$filename;?>&w=389&q=100&f=jpg" />
```

Comment: AFAIK You can't include an image as PHP will try to process the contents of the image file, you could open the image with GD / Imagick and then output it though

Comment: If you're putting code similar to this on a website that anyone other than yourself can access, please (for the sake of everything web-friendly) make sure you sanitize the `$_GET['src']` variable before you actually use it in *any* reading command (i.e. `include()`, `readfile()`, `fopen()`, etc).

Comment: @newfurniturey: Thanks for the information, will do that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send a file to the browser you need to use `readfile($resized_image)`, because `include $resized_image` will attempt to parse the file as a PHP script, which is actually quite dangerous!

See also: [`readfile()`](http://www.php.net/readfile)

Comment: Super fast, works thanks :) Will approve this when possible

Answer (score 1):

Use `readfile()` instead. `include` is the wrong tool, and can lead to security issues too.

Answer (score 1):

to send a image to the browser with php I would do like:

```
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
try
{
    $image = fopen('imagepath', "rb");
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    //foobar
}
fpassthru($image);
fclose($image);
exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

i think it should be more like -> echo $resized_image; in the thumb.php